# Unpublish a 'Time Publishing' app from Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play

In **Standard Publishing** mode, I can hit `Unpublish app` and this will remove the app from the Play Store.

How do I achieve the same in **Timed Publishing** mode? The link for unpublish is not clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unpublish while in 'Time Publishing' mode, you'll have to switch back to 'Standard Publishing'.

Comment: Yeah, figured that one. Any reason why?

Comment: Well, the idea is if you're in that mode, you're intending to update your app. It doesn't make sense to unpublish an app which is due for updating at a particular time.

Answer (score 0):

One way I found out is to switch the app to *Standard Publishing* and then hit the `Unpublish` button. The publishing mode shouldn't matter if the app is going to be removed from the store anyways.